# Why am I getting the error "WM_MENUCOMMAND was not declared in this scope" when I included windows.h?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to make an application that captures selection of context menu items and up until now I've had windows.h included and it seemed to work fine, but for some reason I'm getting an error "WM_MENUCOMMAND was not declared in this scope". I am on windows xp so I meet the minimum system requirements as indicated by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I figure theres no reason it shouldn't work. How do I get WM_MENUCOMMAND to work?

Comment: Is your project split into multiple files?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't #defined `WINVER`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: By default, `WINVER` is defined as 0x500 when not previously defined, and `WM_MENUCOMMAND` is defined when `WINVER >= 0x500`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: are you sure that's correct? I just added #define WINVER 0x500 to my code and it worked, when previously I had not defined winver at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True for MSVC, not necessarily for other compilers (which it seems like the OP is using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_MENUCOMMAND` is defined in `winuser.h` (which `windows.h` includes), but only when `WINVER` is `>= 0x0500` and `_WIN32_WCE` is not defined.  So you likely have `WINVER` set too low.  It is set to `0x0500` by default, so something in your project must be redefining it to a lower value.

Comment: would #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 cause this to happen? I added #define WINVER 0x500 to the top of my code so if something was redefining it it would've been overwritten I would think..

Comment: A default Visual Studio project includes `<SDKDDKVer.h>` to set `WINVER`. The default value depends on the SDK used to compile the project.

Comment: I'm using Code::blocks with MingW. I didn't realize SDK's included their own files, where can I find a list of these hidden includes?